# Time per cycle for 8051 Micro controller

Tags: assembly, 8051

I am programming in Assembly Language, with an 8051 micro controller with a 24.5 MHz crystal on it and a clock cycle divided by 12.

I am busy with a program where I have to display a Signal Train with an LED. Thus I have to program in Delays to achieve the necessary Duty Cycle and Period however ,I am having trouble calculating the time a takes per cycle to complete.

Can anyone please help me with this calculation?

Thank you.

Comment: I think the answer is going to depend on the specific 8051 compatible chip you're using.

Comment: Here is a [nice reference](http://www.8052.com/set8051.phtml) that lists cycle counts (also has an [awesome tutorial section](http://www.8052.com/tut8051) that you might be interested in). Just sum the counts for your code. Consult your chip's datasheet for any possible differences.

Comment: The 24,5 MHz and a div 12 clock sound a lot like some Silabs parts, and those have a modernised pipelined 8051 implementation. Rough estimate was around 1 clock/code byte IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

It requires to calculate machine cycle. Machine cycle is term that shows time to execute one instruction.( Simple instruction like NOP, that requires only one machine cycle to execute other require one or more depends upon instruction execution)

Your crystal frequency is Fctl=24.2MHz

First you divide Fctl into 12 parts. Fctl/12 = 24.2MHz/12= 2.0167MHz

Now This is your machine frequency. Your machine cycle is 
1/machine freq. = 1/2.0167MHz = 0.4959uS

So this is your machine cycle. when you put one NOP instruction it will give you delay of 0.4959uS.

Comment: That tells you the duration of one cycle.  But instructions on 8051 do not retire in one cycle.  The exact number of cycles per instruction varies with the instruction and which 8051 compatible MCU you're using.  You'll need that table from the datasheet.